# Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed while trying to connect to Tor via my college's network even with bridges

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bridge, obfsproxy, error, meek

Till 3 days ago everything was fine, Tor browser 6.0.4 was connecting very well and even Vidalia Tor bundle too.

But now, none of them are connecting from any PC through my college network.

My configurations are:
System : windows 7, 32-bit
local proxy: proxy.xxxxxx.in ,  port :31xx

For the **Tor Browser 6.0.4** , earlier I was using **meek-azure bridges** but now it is showing error and the **error log** is as :

```
09-09-2016 12:59:43.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09-09-2016 13:01:28.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09-09-2016 13:01:28.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09-09-2016 13:01:28.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09-09-2016 13:01:28.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09-09-2016 13:01:37.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
09-09-2016 13:01:37.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
09-09-2016 13:01:38.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44 at 0.0.2.0:3) 
09-09-2016 13:01:38.100 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
09-09-2016 13:01:38.100 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
09-09-2016 13:03:36.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09-09-2016 13:03:36.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09-09-2016 13:03:36.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

I have tried **obfs3 bridges** also but it failed too. **Error log** is as :

```
09-09-2016 13:07:36.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09-09-2016 13:07:36.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09-09-2016 13:07:36.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09-09-2016 13:07:36.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09-09-2016 13:07:47.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
09-09-2016 13:09:00.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09-09-2016 13:09:00.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09-09-2016 13:09:00.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

I hope you guys could really help me here.

Comment: Have you tried other PTs bridges?

Comment: yeah pal,  I have tried obfs4 and fte bridges too, but it failed. it is even not connecting with directory server

Comment: Can you connect to the Meek CDN fronts normally e.g. https://a0.awsstatic.com (meek amazon) or https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com (meek azure)?

Comment: I tried with meek-amazon bridges and it connected but it is too slow and  disconnects after 2 to 3 min.

Comment: Right, but what happens if you open those links in a normal browser?